# How to make correct regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I want to get ${1} = Title, ${2} = Open, ${3} = Bla-bla-bla.

from

```
{{Title|Open
Bla-bla-bla 
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
$str = <<<STR
{{Title|Open
Bla-bla-bla 
}}
STR;

$matches = array();
if (preg_match("/^\{\{([^\|]+)\|([^\n]+)(.*)\}\}$/s", $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

It'll get you :

```
array
  0 => string '{{Title|Open
Bla-bla-bla 
}}' (length=28)
  1 => string 'Title' (length=5)
  2 => string 'Open' (length=4)
  3 => string '
Bla-bla-bla 
' (length=14)
```

Which means that, after using [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) on `$matches[1]`, `$matches[2]`, and `$matches[3]`, you'll get what you asked for :-)

Explaining the regex :

- matching from the beginning of the string : `^`
- two `{` characters, that have to be escaped, as they have a special meaning
- anything that's not a |, at least one time : `[^\|]+`

  - between `()` so it's captured -- returned as the first part of the result
  - `|` has to be escaped too.
- a `|` character -- that has to be escaped.
- Anything that's not a line-break, at least one time : `[^\n]+`

  - between `()` so it's captured too -- second part of the result
- `.*` virtually "anything" anynumber of times

  - between `()` so it's captured too -- third part of the result
- and, finally, two `}` *(escaped, too)*
- and an end of string : `$`

And note the regex has the `s` *(dotall)* modifier ; see [Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), about that.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "{{Title|Open
Bla-bla-bla 
}}";

preg_match('/^\{\{([^|]+)\|(.*?)[\r\n]+(.*?)\s*\}\}/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

a useful place to play around and learn regexes.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
/\{\{         # literal opening braces
 (.*?)        # some characters except new line (lazy, i. e. as less as possible)
 \|           # literal pipe
 (.*?)        # same as 2 lines above
 \n           # new line
 ([\s\S]*?)   # any character, including new line (lazy)
 \}\}/x;      # literal closing braces
```

Making a more precise solution depends on what exact rules you want for extraction of your fields.